# Active Directory File System in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Dear All,
What is Active Directory File System in Sharepoint 2010? How can we use it in Sandboxed solutions?

Anoop George Thomas

Comment: Where have you seen this? ADFS = Active Directory Federation Services, are you confusing it with this?

Answer (score 0):

As James says in his comment. There is no thing as AD File System. AD FS is the "official" name of Active Directory.

And no, you can't access AD from a Sandboxed solution.